# Rails ActiveRecord Relationship Invalid Foreign Key Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails (using 5.1) and I'm having trouble setting up my ActiveRecord associations.

Organizers can sign up and then create a club. An organizer belongs to one club (I guess could potentially have multiple but for now it's fine to expect just one). Clubs can have many organizers.

Clubs will always be created after the Organizer has been created so the foreign key on clubs is nil initially.

Here's the error I'm getting when trying to create an organizer without having any clubs already created:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:         ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "organizers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_bc04936880"
        DETAIL:  Key (club_id)=(0) is not present in table "club".
```

Organizer:

```
class Organizer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :club, optional: true 
    #also put config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false in application.rb
end
```

Club:

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
    has_many: organizers
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "clubs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "full_name"
    t.string "urn"
    t.string "short_name"
    t.string "address1"
    t.string "address2"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "website"
    t.string "phone"
  end

  create_table "organizers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.boolean "superuser", default: false
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated", default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.bigint "club_id"
    t.index ["club_id"], name: "index_organizers_on_club_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_organizers_on_email", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "organizers", "clubs"
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your error is probably coming from elsewhere. Rails is looking for club_id on table club. Table club won’t have that, it will have just id.

Comment: Thanks for the input @DavidWeber! It looks like the error is saying that the foreign key club_id (on the organizers table) isn't a vaild primary key on the clubs table (since right now there are no clubs). Though I set that foreign key to be optional so I'd think I wouldn't get this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us how do you create the Organizer record?

Comment: Did you write your schema or are you using migrations? I am not sure in rails 5 but I would think you need a `"clubs", ["club_id"], name: "index_clubs_on_organizer", using: :btree` or something.

Comment: @DavidWeber Yea it's weird because I'm using migrations, but the flow of my application is a bit different than others I've seen (as you create the user (organizer) before it's parent (club) is actually created). Thanks, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason your code tries to set `0` value to `club_id`.

I would suggest forcing `nil` in this attribute and observe if error still occurs:

```
Organizer.create!(
  #...
  club_id = nil
)
```